# Tesseract accuracy in screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to fetch score info from a Dota2 screenshot (disregard the "wrong" boxes on the borders)

[image: original image]

but I can't seem to get a good enough accuracy

[image: after tesseract]
I'm applying these filters to the image

```py
bw_image = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
bw_image = cv2.cvtColor(bw_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

and this config to tesseract
`config = ("-l eng --oem 1 --psm 7")`

In the screenshot provided the **ROI** was resized to (50,50) but resizing doesn't impact accuracy consistently

How can I improve my results? I searched how to train/improve a tesseract model but it seems to much work for what I want.

Comment: as I remeber `tesseract` was created for scaners which scan white papers with black text, and rather not for images. It doesn't know if you can train it - it may not use machine learning or neural network.

Comment: I found information about [training tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract) but it seems it needs long work. Maybe first try to crop image to keep only region with value and make more image modification - like change constrast - to create better image for OCR. See [Improving the quality of the output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)